# Выдает <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7e3f498dd0> при цикле и так бесконечно.Что делать?

Tags: python, while

````
from random import *

password = '12'
cm = '123'#qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'


b = cm
run = True
if b != password:
   while run:
      b =  ("".join(choice(b)) for x in range(1,12))
      print(b)
else:
   run = False  ```
````

Comment: поменять `b =  ("".join(choice(b)) for x in range(1,12))` на `b =  ["".join(choice(b)) for x in range(1,12)]`?

Comment: Бесконечно, потому что у вас условие цикла `while run:` такое, а `("".join(choice(b)) for x in range(1,12))` - это генератор, у него синтаксис схож с генератором списка, только круглые скобки используются

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как я понял, вы хотите сделать подборщик пароля и вам нужна переменная b в виде строки. Так как b=cm, можно сделать так:

```
from random import *

password = '12'
cm = '123'#qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'


b = cm
run = True
if b != password:
   while run:
      b =  ''
      for x in range(1, 12):
          b += choice(cm)
      print(b)
else:
   run = False
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы b было в виде списка, то можно сделать так:

```
from random import *

password = '12'
cm = '123'#qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'


b = cm
run = True
if b != password:
   while run:
      b =  [choice(cm) for x in range(1, 12)]
      print(b)
else:
   run = False
```

Но, честно говоря, рандомный подбор символов - не лучший способ подобрать пароль.